# Difference between PRIMARY KEY and SERIAL (with index)

Tags: postgresql, index

Is there any difference between a table with a field defined as

```
userId serial PRIMARY KEY
```

and a table with a field defined as

```
userId serial
```

and then having an index created on the field `userId`?

`serial` is by definition `unique` and `NOT NULL` but doesn't come with a default index. So I assume the two are functionally equivalent?

Comment: Uniqness is usuall implemented via an UNIQUE index, so are you sure that they are guaeanteed to be unique but there is not an index there to guarantee it?

Comment: `serial` is [discouraged](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_serial) anyway

Comment: "*serial is by definition unique*" - no it's not. The generated values might be unique, but the `serial`pseudo-type does not include the declaration of a unique constraint. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=c26db6a53747fde677df4439a12d4fd7

Answer (score 1):

Defining a column as `serial` creates the column as type `integer` with `NOT NULL` and a `DEFAULT` value taken from a sequence. It does *not* make the column unique: you can for example insert a row with a `userid` that already exists if you override the default value with an explicit value.

There are two things missing:

- a unique index on the column
- a primary key constraint on the column that is implemented with the above index

If you create the constraint, the index is created automatically. The constraint seems like an unnecessary adornment at first glance: after all, the index alone already guarantees uniqueness. There are two reasons why a constraint is a good idea, though:

- You need a primary key or unique constraint as the target of a foreign key constraint.
- Indexes are not part of the SQL standard, but constraints are. As a consequence, you will only find the constraint in the `information_schema`, and tools that use introspection to reverse engineer the structure of the database are much more likely to detect the constraint than the index.

Answer (score 0):

The are not identical. You can for example not reference a serial column in a foreign key unless it is declared as UNIQUE/PRIMARY KEY:

```
create table T (x serial, y int not null);
create table U (x int not null references T(x));
ERROR:  there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "t"
```

If you reset your sequence you can reuse the same serial numbers without a complaint

```
insert into T (y) values (1),(1),(1);
ALTER SEQUENCE T_X_seq RESTART WITH 1;
insert into T (y) values (1),(1),(1);

select * from T;
x   y
1   1
2   1
3   1
1   1
2   1
3   1
```

Hence, a serial column is not guaranteed to be unique unless it is declared that way

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=7170da9e77eb6275db85eb9f270f9db7)